# CONCEPTS IN EVOLUTIONARY ALGORITHMS

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

HOW ARE THESE TWO CONCEPTS OFTEN ENCOUNTERED WHEN STUDYING THE FIELD OF EVOLUTIONARY ALGORITHMS.

- GENOTYPE
- OPTIMISATION PROBLEMS

??

Comment: Step 1: Fix your shift-key, Step 2: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's all caps

Answer (score 0):

These are two unrelated concepts.

Genotypes are a class of organisms with identical genomes.  A genome is the specific information in an organism (the DNA of an individual in nature).  These terms are used commonly in evolutionary biology, but not quite as common in evolutionary computation.  In general, genotypes are a "type" or organism with the same genetic information.

Optimization Problems are well-defined functions where you are trying to find the input that produces an overall maximum or minimum.  Evolutionary computation is frequently used on these sorts of problems.